# ¿Cómo graficar rectángulos en R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo la siguiente tabla en `R` (dt.productos):

```
str(dt.productos)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   75 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Familia   : chr  "PRODUCTO A" "PRODUCTO B" "PRODUCTO B" "PRODUCTO C" ...
 $ Producto  : chr  "AB" "AC" "AC" "AD" ...
 $ Causa     : chr  "RESCA" "RESCA" "VENTO" "FNAT" ...
 $ Casos: num  2 7 4 3 2 2 1 1 14 12 ...
```

Según la cual tiene 75 filas y 4 columnas.

Lo que quiero sacar en R es una gráfica de datos en bloques de rectángulos, de dos columnas en concreto: `Causa` y `Casos`.

En `excel` tengo la siguiente gráfica:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en R tengo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código para llegar a ese gráfico en `R` es el siguiente:

```
plot(table(dt.productos$Causa, dt.productos$Casos), main="Título", 
col=c("lightblue", "lightpink"))
```

Pero como se puede apreciar nada tiene que ver con el que tengo en excel, he probado incluso a mostrar los que tengan más de 50 casos, pero no es que haya logrado mucho.

Como no consigo reproducir el mismo gráfico tampoco he seguido indagando, pero por ejemplo, el texto de cada causa también tendría que estar en su caja correspondiente, cosa que en R tampoco logro.

De hecho lo he intentando con `ggplot + geom_rect` y el resultado es tan desastroso que prefiero no poner la captura.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: para hacer algo parecido a lo de tu excel yo utilizo treemap en vez de ggplot. dale un vistazo a https://rpubs.com/brandonkopp/creating-a-treemap-in-r

Comment: Gracias @patovega me ha venido genial, de forma fácil y rápida he podido implementar el gráfico en rectángulo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código con el que estás probando va a dar como resultado un gráfico de mosaico, en el que se grafican las probabilidades (proporciones) condicionales. Lo que te interesa es graficar las proporciones totales.

Como señala @patovega ese tipo de gráfico es un treemap. Con `ggplot2` se puede hacer con la librería `treemapify::`, que se encarga de hacer los (complejos) cálculos de tamaños y ubicación de los rectángulos y produce el elemento geométrico en el plot.

Para hacer un treemap necesitas un data.frame (si no ggplot no anda!) que contenga:

- Una columna numérica, proporcional a cuya magnitud será el área de cada rectángulo. Es la variable de mayor interés y se mapea al argumento `area=`. Con esta es suficiente, pero el gráfico sería muy pobre, de hecho en este caso sería mejor trabajar directamente con barras.
- Una columna numérica o categórica (factor, character) cuyo valor o magnitud controlará el color de cada rectángulo y se mapea con `fill=`. `ggplot` elige la escala correcta. Es ideal para graficar otra propiedad de tus filas, no para etiquetar casos ya que...
- Una columna categórica en la que se indique las etiquetas (nombres) de cada rectáctangulo. Se mapea con el argumento `label=`

En tu caso el código sería:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(treemapify)
ggplot(dt.productos, aes(ares = casos, fill = causa, label = causa)) 
  geom_treemap() + 
  geom_treemap_text(place = "centre",grow = TRUE)
```

No puedo probarlo porque no tengo los datos completos, pero con los datos `G20` que trae de ejemplo `treemapify::` funciona.

Va ejemplo:

```
  ggplot(G20, aes(area = gdp_mil_usd, 
                  fill = econ_classification, 
                  label = country)) +
    geom_treemap() + 
    geom_treemap_text(place = "centre",grow = TRUE) +
    labs(title = "Funcionan los títulos de ggplot", 
         caption = "También otros atributos\npara personaliar el gráfico")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por su solución que me va a venir muy bien igualmente para entender un poco más los ggplot, porque no daba con la forma de usarlo en este caso. Aunque treemap lo considero una herramienta muy buena, usar además ggplot siempre amplía posibilidades, en función de las necesidades.